# Python elasticsearch timeout

Tags: python, elasticsearch

In queries like aggregations and cardinality search there might be a timeout.

I noticed that when executing queries from python client the response sometimes contains:

```
{  
   "took":1200184,
   "timed_out":true,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":84,
      "successful":84,
      "failed":0
   }
```

And returns less results than the expected.

My main problem is that when timeout occurs, response still contains a number of results.
I could check if timeout is true before parsing response results but there is probably a better way to do that :)... `like raise an exception` or `somehow catch timeout and retry`

Comment: I have a similar problem, except that the "took" value is much less - 82 milliseconds only.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase the timeout for elasticsearch using:-

```
es.search(index="my_index",
      doc_type="document",
      body=get_req_body(),
      request_timeout=30)
```

By default the value assigned is 10. If ,on the other hand you want to catch exception you can use a scheduler and check the time elapsed and catch the exception if it exceeds the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch-py client has a named argument you can pass that will let you set timeout value for the search request.

But I'd suggest using scrolling to obtain results in such scenarios, it is similar to a cursor for database query. Here's a really good [example](https://gist.github.com/drorata/146ce50807d16fd4a6aa) of how to use scrolling. With a limited scroll size, the request is less likely to timeout and you will be able to fetch all the results instead of receiving partial results.

**Example search call with timeout parameter**

```
es.search(index="index", doc_type="doc_type", body=body, timeout=50)
```